# cookie notice not showing

Tags: magento2.3, cookie, notice

I have Magento 2.3.
Cookie Restriction mode is enabled in the admin panel but not showing on the home page.
the style after load page [display is none ]  but the style on CSS  [display is block]

---

this image from css theme

[image]

---

and this image after load page

[image]

---

i flushed all cache but not working. how can i solve this

Comment: this is multi store  web-site???

Comment: Yes . it is mutli store view  [1 Website -1 store - 3 store view] . and is enabled on all store view

Comment: Cookie restriction mode is enable on all store view but it not showing

Comment: i think you try clear var/cache and var/view_preprocessed and apply permission...

Comment: it  worked once and then stopped

Comment: i think cache issues...

Comment: how can I solve this.!?